# asp.net - session problem

Tags: asp.net, session

i lunched an asp.net web-site. the main idea in the site is that:
the site shows the same page, but on each next button the user clicks, the pictures in the site change randomly. im working with postback and sessions.

i noticed that when a few users try to log into my site - their sessions are merging. meaning, the first picture presented is diffrent but the second picture is the same for all the users, and so on... (moreover, pictures that appears in the begining appearing again even thow i don't allw it in my code)

when i tried to debug the site locally, the random function works perfectly and there were no such problems. it haapens only when 2 users and more log into my site.

any suugestion how to solve it?

lots of thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the code where you generate the random picture?

Answer (score 0):

Is your randomizer declared as static?